# Xamarin UI Test: Is it possible to interact with the OS level dialogues during UITesting

Tags: c#, testing, xamarin, xamarin.forms, automated-tests

Is it possible to automate OS level dialogues during xamarin UI testing?
I.E - Tap the upload button, which brings up a gallery modal which would allow you to select a photo of your choice to upload? Or tapping an overflow menu and be given the choice to open via external app, or go fullscreen?

Is it possible to automate the selection of the photo? Is it possible to trigger airplane mode so the app is offline during the test execution? I'm just trying to find out how limited i am when it comes to automating the app im responsible for as there are a few scenarios like this.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in one post, so the answer can have one objective accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not *within* your app's process/sandbox, *typically* you can not access it with `UITest` (items like system dialog/prompts are auto'd accepted...).

In terms of tapping an overflow menu and selecting an action, yes, that is within your app and thus can be automated.

For picking a picture say from the iOS' Galley via  `UIImagePickerController`, you will "see" the controller via a `RemoteViewBridge`, **but** elements within that, i.e. the actual selectable pictures in the galley, you will not see via the UITest agent as they are sandboxed outside of your app process.. You can use `.TapCoordinates(x,y)` to tap on the screen, and thus pick a picture. Yes, those coordinates change depending upon device size, etc... but it is possible... :-/

UITest does support Casabash's features like backdoors, so if the platform supports a programmatically way to do something, then you could code it into your code and call that method via UITest. So, on a ***rooted*** Android device you could code a method that enables airplane mode and call that via a test backdoor, but on off-self Android and iOS devices setting airplane mode would be impossible.

Now with test frameworks like Appium it is possible to drive system apps (iOS' Safari, Setting, etc...) as you basically have full access to the iOS' XCUITest and Android instrumentation framework so ***almost*** anything is possible with *enough* test coding.

Microsoft does have some overview doc(s) on testing frameworks:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/migration/test-cloud/frameworks